# I have multiple, structurally identical schemas in postgres. Is there a way to "code-share" views and queries

Tags: postgresql

In my multi-tenant postgres database, I have a schema per tenant for my data warehouse with the same tables in each.
I wish to create views and queries for these tables. If I were programming I would practice DRY and structure my code so that all of these were parameterised by the tenant. How do I achieve a similar structure in postgres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the same queries on different schemas just by changing `search_path` variable.

```
set search_path = schema1;
select * from orders; -- resolves to schema1.orders

set search_path = schema2;
select * from orders; -- resolves to schema2.orders
```

As for views, you will have create/drop them individually across all schemas just like you do with the tables.